# DataReader : Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have faced some interesting situation. I have the following code to populate value of field from DB (ASP.net):

```
SqlConnection connect =
            new SqlConnection(
                @"conn-string"); 
SqlCommand toDo = new SqlCommand(InfoQuery, connect);
        toDo.CommandTimeout = 6000;
        connect.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = toDo.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ///......retrieving some fields in the same way as below
                    foo = reader.SafeGetString(7);
                    int temp = reader.SafeGetInt32(8);
                    ///......retrieving again
                }
        }
        connect.close()
```

The connection is established, all params are correct. In SQL Server Management Studio the query associated with `toDo` command works just perfect. In program when running every field to the `temp` value (not including temp) is retrieved and set. But when reading temp value, i get the following exception:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

And here are my extension methods:

```
public static class ExtentionMethods
{
    public static string SafeGetString(this SqlDataReader reader, int colIndex)
    {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
            return reader.GetString(colIndex);
        return "NULL VALUE";
    }

    public static int SafeGetInt32(this SqlDataReader reader, int colIndex)
    {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
            return reader.GetInt32(colIndex);
        return -1;
    }

    public static DateTime SafeGetDateTime(this SqlDataReader reader, int colIndex)
    {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
        {
            try
            {
            }
            catch
            {
                return new DateTime(1800, 1, 1);
            }
        }
        return new DateTime(1800, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID0]
        ,[Id1]
        ,[Id2]
        ,Id1+Id2+'0' AS BC
        ,[Id3]
        ,[Id4]
        ,[Id5]
        ,CAST([Date] AS nvarchar(max))
        ,[int]
        ,[Id7]
        ,[Id8]
        ,IsNull(foo,'dsf')+' '+IsNull(bar,'dsf')+', '
        +IsNull(fgm,'fggf')+', fgfggf '+IsNull(gfgf,'gfgf')+
        ','+dfsdfsdsf+', '+dsffddf AS dsadsa
        ,[fg]
        ,[fds]
        FROM tbl
        inner join tbl1 on tbl1.ID=ID1
        inner join tbl2 on tbl2.ID=ID2
        WHERE Id4=12
```

What the problem could be?

Comment: Where is the connection declared and when it is initialized? Do you use `using-statement` for it also?

Comment: Are those 7/8 supposed to be ordinal positions? I would strongly recommend you use column names and not ordinal positions. Yikes.

Comment: What does SafeGetString do? Does it just check for DbNull and then return either string.empty or the value?

Comment: I'm not using-statement for connection object. However it is declared few lines upper and is close using-statement.

Comment: Is the connection static? Can you show more of this method? I don't understand the last sentence of your last comment.

Comment: @ConradFrix, edited my post for your question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, updated my source, connection is not static.

Comment: @seeker: I strongly recommend to use `using-statement` also for the connection and the SqlCommand(both implement IDisposable). It's very important to always close a connection, all the more in ASP.NET. Your connection would stay open in case of an exception. Have you used the debugger to see what happens, is it reproducable?

Comment: @AaronBertrand It doesn't actually matter. The check for a valid reader happens before the check of the position. Even if the reverse were true you'd get an IndexOutOfRangeException rather than an InvalidOperationException

Comment: @TimSchmelter I used debugger. Exception is thrown in `SafeGetInt32` method in the line  `if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))`

Comment: @KingCronus, I can not post query for security reasons. But as i mentioned IN SSMS it works all right.

Comment: @ConradFrix I didn't mean as a way to fix this error, which is why it's a comment and not an answer. I just meant as a general best practice. Counting columns in the query to be sure the ordinal you've picked is still correct is really annoying.

Comment: @seeker so you can't post the query and change table/column names to foo/bar etc.? Really?

Comment: @AaronBertrand about your tip not to use ordinal positions. If I use something like `reader["field"]` then i will get exception when object is null. And in my DB object may be null. So this approach is inappropriate here

Comment: edited query will be posted in a minute

Comment: do you have an extra `reader.Read()` somewhere? I ask because pretty much every other bad thing I tried (`connect.close()`, extra call to `executeReader()`, setting low timeouts, shutting down sql server) resulted in a different error

Comment: The problem is solved. The problem was invalid casting. I have no idea, why that type of error wasn't thrown, but after adding conversion everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need all this extensions methods, and you should access columns by name :

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    int intCol = reader["MyIntColumn"] as int? ?? -1;
    string stringCol = reader["MyStringColumn"] as string ?? "NULL VALUE";
    DateTime dateCol = reader["MyDateColumn"] as DateTime? ?? new DateTime(1800, 1, 1);
}
```

`int?` or `DateTime?` will allow nulls and `??` will affect a default value if the column is null.